# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' SystemJs ( 0.21.5v )

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, systemjs, core-js

I have Angular 9.0v and NodeJS 12.16v, systemjs 0.21.5v, core-js 2.6.9v in my package.json file. 
I am getting this error -

```
(index):153 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at eval (<anonymous>)
at evaluate (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:2860:18)
at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:3665:23
at doEvaluateDynamic (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:1166:33)
at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:1026:17
at doEvaluateDynamic (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:1163:9)
at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1582797940325:1026:17
at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/app/main.js:3:14)
at eval (http://localhost:8080/app/main.js:13:4)
at eval (http://localhost:8080/app/main.js:14:3) Not expecting this error? Report it at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-  seed/issues
```

I have server and client. This is src/client file which has the main issue. Server is running.
App.module.ts

```js
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { Http, HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRequestOptions, LoaderService, MessageService, SessionStorageService, ThemeChangeService,
  BaseService, CommonService } from './shared/index';
import { ContactService } from './framework/dashboard/contact/contact.service';
import { ContactService1 } from  './framework/home-page/home-page.service';
import { ActivateUserComponent } from './framework/registration/activate-user/activate-user.component';
import { ActiveUserService } from './framework/registration/activate-user/activate-user.service';
import { RedirectRecruiterDashboardService } from './user/services/redirect-dashboard.service';
import { LoggerService, MyErrorHandler } from './build-info/framework/my-error-handler.service';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CustomHttp } from './shared/services/http/custom.http';
import { SharedService } from './shared/services/shared-service';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './shared/services/auth-guard.service';
import { HttpDelegateService } from './shared/services/http-delegate.service';
//Application IMPORTS
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ValidationService} from './shared/customvalidations/validation.service';
import {ErrorService} from './shared/services/error.service';
import {UsageTrackingService} from './build-info/framework/usage-tracking.service';
import {CreateProjectModule} from './build-info/framework/create-project/create-project.module';
import {DashboardModule} from './framework/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import {BuildingModule} from './build-info/framework/project/building/building.module';
import {ResetPasswordModule} from './framework/login/forgot-password/reset-password/reset-password.module';
import {CreateBuildingModule} from './build-info/framework/project/building/create-building/create-building.module';
import {LoginModule} from './framework/login/login.module';
import {CandidateSignUpModule} from './framework/registration/candidate-sign-up/candidate-sign-up.module';
import {ForgotPasswordModule} from "./framework/login/forgot-password/forgot-password.module";
import { AdminComponent } from './build-info/framework/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminService } from './build-info/framework/admin/admin.service';
import {ProjectHeaderVisibilityService} from "./shared/services/project-header-visibility.service";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    UserModule,
    CreateProjectModule,
    CreateBuildingModule,
    BuildingModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ResetPasswordModule,
    ForgotPasswordModule,
    LoginModule,
    CandidateSignUpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ActivateUserComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    AdminComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, MessageService, LoaderService]
    },
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppRequestOptions},
    LoggerService, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler},
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },
    ContactService,
    ContactService1,
    ActiveUserService,
    RedirectRecruiterDashboardService,
    SharedService,
    Title,
    AuthGuardService,
    HttpDelegateService,
    LoaderService,
    UsageTrackingService,
    ValidationService,
    SessionStorageService,
    MessageService,
    SharedService,
    ThemeChangeService, CommonService, BaseService, CustomHttp, ErrorService, SessionStorageService,
    AdminService,
    ProjectHeaderVisibilityService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}

export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, messageService: MessageService,
                            loaderService: LoaderService) {
  return  new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, messageService, loaderService);
}
```

Here above code is app.module.ts

Comment: Most probably you have a simple typo somewhere in your code. First step would be search for all `<` character in your code. Second, try to use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). It is very helpful in mitigating these kind of situations.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. I think it's related to packages or some modules changed.

Comment: Could you please show your app.module file?

Comment: Please see above attachment app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the network tab whether all the packages have been loaded properly or not or if you see html in that package then it means file is not found yet.

This is because node modules were not loaded properly. I fixed this issue by importing all the modules in a single **system.config.ts**.

Also add these lines in index.html

```
<script src="<%= APP_BASE %>app/system-config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err) })
</script>
```

system.config.ts

```js
SystemJS.config({
  paths: {
    ['app/main'] : `app/main`,
    '@angular/animations':
      'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations':
      'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler':
      'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/core': 'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/common/http': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser':
      'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':
      'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser':
      'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/core/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/http/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing':
      'node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    'html2canvas': 'node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js',
    'lodash': 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
    'device_uuid': 'node_modules/device-uuid/lib/device-uuid.min.js',
    'highcharts': 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js',
    'jspdf': 'node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js',
    'app/': `/app/`,
    // For test config
    'dist/dev/': '/base/dist/dev/',
    '': 'node_modules/',
  },
  packages: {
    'app': {
      main: 'main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs/operators': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs/internal/operators': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
  }
  });
```